# regarding counting the number of columns in gvim

Tags: linux, vim

After opening a big csv file in gvim, how can I know how many columns are within this file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick dirty hack would be to do something like:

```
:s/,//gn
```

Which would give you the number of commas on a single row.  Add one and you have your number of columns (assuming no trailing comma, of course).

I say this is quick and dirty because it doesn't take into account quoted columns which can contain commas.  I'm sure there might be a way to take that into account with a regex but it's probably not trivial.

Answer (score 4):

The [csv.vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2830) provides a lot of functionality to work with CSV data. It includes a `:NrColumns` command.